# How do I round these number to get the wanted result

Tags: flutter, dart

I build a flutter application to my work and I want to round these number but I couldn't find the proper formula so please help me to find it

example:

```
var theWeight;
var theFee;

theWeight= 1;
// I want the result: theFee= 1;

theWeight= 999;
// I want the result: theFee= 1;

theWeight= 1000;
// I want the result: theFee= 1;

theWeight= 1001;
// I want the result: theFee= 2;

theWeight= 2000;
// I want the result: theFee= 2;

theWeight= 2001;
// I want the result: theFee= 3;
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to specify the fee? As I understand you would like to create sort of mapping that if weight is over a thousand the fee should go to two? Or would you like 2002 to present a fee of 3?

Comment: You need to provide more examples.  You haven't provided enough data points for people to discern what exact pattern you want.  Describing the rules you want the pattern to follow would be even better.

Comment: yes I want 2002= 3 , 1=1, 1000=1, 1001=2, 2000=2, 2001=3 and so on...
the fee=weight(rounded)/1000, 
but also the weight if less 1000 like 50 fee=1,
hope you understand  what I looking for;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't try :

`theFee = (theWeight/1000).ceil();`